# PHP check | (OR) operator in variable assignment

Tags: php, operators, operator-keyword, assign

I want to check two variables `a` and `b` and assign both the variable to new variable "c" and want to get the `OR` result from both the variables. for example if `a=1` and `b=0`, `c` must be 1, while if `a=0` and `b=1`, `c` must be 1, if `a=0` and `b=0` then `c=0`, for this purpose i am using the following `|` operator, which returns the required result, but i am not sure if i am doing it correct or not

```
<?php 
$a = 0; 
$b = 1;     
$c = $a | $b;
echo("Value in $c = ".$c); 
?>
```

EDIT: i have gone through the PHP.NET website and find that:

```
 $a | $b    Or (inclusive or)   Bits that are set in either $a or $b are set.
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: `|` is bitwise or. you might be looking for `||` (which is a logical or)

Comment: but i have just checked the || operator which is not return the required result?

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between bitwise (`|`, `&`, ...) and logical (`&&`, `||`,...) operators.

Comment: you are doing it right if you mean bitwise OR. except you don't need the last `?>`

Comment: w3schools says that you have to used "OR" operator or "||" both are working in such scenario but the test returns nothing when both "a" and "b" has "0" value in it.

Comment: In your scenario you really need the bitwise or `|` and you are doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only have the states you have in your question, you can use a ternary to do this. It might help others understand what you're doing in the future

```
$c = ($a || $b) ? 1 : 0;
```

There's nothing wrong with the way you did it in your question, tho.

Comment: what if $a=1 and $b = 1, then $c will be "0" right?

Comment: while i need to get $c = 1 if either is "1" in both the variable "a" and "b"

Comment: @Machavity the code you wrote returns the same result like my code? isn't?

Comment: @AbdulRahman There's nothing wrong with your way. Mine is just a different way that might be easier to understand. Same result